# cURL command with parameters returned by python -c "python code here" command

Tags: python, linux, shell, curl

I have this command

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json | python -c "import json; print (' '.join(['-d '+key+'='+word for key,word in json.load(open('cron_parameters_testing.json')).items() ] ))"
```

actually the python command reads parameters from JSON file like this

{
'project' : 'default'
}

and returns the output as `-d project=default`

I have separately tested `python -c "import json; print (' '.join(['-d '+key+'='+word for key,word in json.load(open('cron_parameters_testing.json')).items() ] ))` command it works perfectly but it does work with the cURL

my final command that I want to run is

`curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=default`

of course I want `-d project=default` to be generated from command I mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` is a pipe, in your case it sends standard output from `curl` to become the standard input to python. This seems unrelated to your task. Try:

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json `python -c "import json; print (' '.join(['-d '+key+'='+word for key,word in json.load(open('cron_parameters_testing.json')).items() ] ))"`
```

The backticks (`` `...` ``) evaluate the command inside and get substituted with the output of the command. Alternatively you can use `$(...)`, especially if you need to nest commands like this.

Comment: in my Ubuntu 14 in VMWare that command works ... but I have a live server with same Ubuntu 14 it does not work ... gives error 

`TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, bool found`

Comment: @Umair That's purely a python error, thought I can't see what would cause it. What are the outputs of `python --version` on both machines? Are the JSON files exactly the same? Are there any non-strings in the JSON file(s)?

Comment: Yeah, file's content was different